# What does const char*** mean and how does it translate from C to Java?

Tags: java, c++, c, jna

I am using **JNA** to write a Java interface for a **C++** written DLL for control of a small device.

While translating data types I came across

```
const char*** someVariable
```

Can someone please explain to me what this means and how can it be recreated in Java?

I have read up on pointers and I am using the JNA documentation to map C++ types  to Java but I cannot find a reference to a type with three asterisks at the end.

Should this be interpreted as a pointer to a String array?

Comment: It is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to `const char`. Unfortunately it can be interpreted in many ways.

Comment: I would look at as a 2d array of c-style strings.

Comment: You might just have seen the work of a [three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer). It is probably a list of a list of strings.

Comment: It means someone can't be bothered to abstract data types properly. You'll have to read the documentation (or the code that uses it) to figure out why there's so much indirection.

Comment: the closest thing you can get in java is a static [][] char variableName;

Comment: as @juanchopanza says, it can be a 3-dimensional matrix, can be an array of arrays of strings, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation is not very useful. There are a lot of things missing. Very basic API description.
It's some kind of Japanese money counting device. I was told that it's actually considered good practice in the field for the manufacturer to write as little code as possible for the device because the varied implementations that banks will have to pay for is less of a security risk than making everything simple and easy to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you know the concept of pointers,

const char*** means it is a triple pointer, so you can think of it this way:

```
const char***--->const char**--->const char*--->const char
```

So yes it can be interpreted as a pointer to a string array, because a string array can be interpreted as a double pointer.

let's say `a` is an array of strings:

```
const char *a[15];
```

In this case `**a` would give you the first char of the first string in a.

you can declare:

```
const char ***b = &a;
```

in this case `***b` would give you the first char of the first string in a.

Comment: But a string array is not a double pointer. It is an array of strings.

Comment: you can interpret it as a double pointer, and you can also use a double pointer as a string array, it depends how you wanna program.

Comment: yes they are not pointers, I edited it. I said it can be interpreted as a double pointer, in C arrays and pointers are closely related, but yes an array is not a pointer. That is not what I am arguing, he asks if it can be INTERPRETED as a pointer to an array of strings, so the answer is yes.

Answer (score 3):

The most *likely* interpretation is that you are expected to pass in the address of a pointer, and on return, the pointer will be an array of C strings.

That's not the only possible interpretation, but probably the most likely one.  This is especially true if the native signature also asks for a pointer to integer into which it will write the length of the returned array.

To use this from JNA:

```
PointerByReference pref = new PointerByReference();
IntegerByReference iref = new IntegerByReference();
nativeLib.call(pref, iref);
String[] strings = pref.getValue().getStringArray(0, iref.getValue());
```

If no length is specified, JNA will look for a NULL value marking the end of the string array.